# SwiftUI parse Multilayer JSON Data from URL and build list

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

First an information: I am actually on the way learning swiftUI, I'm a total newbie. For my first project i decided to create a small app that loads articles from a joomla website. My API will respond to a query in the following structure:

```
{
"source": "my AppConnector for Joomla!",
"offset": 0,
"count": 0,
"results": [
    {
        "id": "8",
        "title": "Article 1",
        ...
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "title": "Article 2",
        ...
    }
]
```

}

In the future the API will return more complex structures but actually i'm struggling already with that one. All swiftUI examples & videos i've found are just explaining how to retreive an array of items or are to old and shows depreacet code examples (with the one-dimensional examples i have already successfully created a list view of items but that's not what i want).

I've created the following structs:

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let source: String
    let offset, count: Int
    let results: [Result]
}


// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let id, title, alias, introtext: String
    let fulltext, state, catid, created: String
    let createdBy, createdByAlias, modified, modifiedBy: String
    let checkedOut, checkedOutTime, publishUp, publishDown: String
    let images, urls, attribs, version: String
    let ordering, metakey, metadesc, access: String
    let hits, metadata, featured, language: String
    let xreference, note, slug, articleID: String
    let introImage, fullImage: String
}
```

and the following fetcher:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine


public class ArticlesFetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var articles = [Welcome]()
    
    init(){
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://nx-productions.ch/index.php/news")! //This is a public demo url feel free to check the jsondata (SecurityToken temporary disabled)
    
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response,error) in
            do {
                if let d = data {
                    let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode([Welcome].self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.articles = decodedLists
                    }
                }else {
                    print("No Data")
                }
            } catch {
                print ("Error")
            }
            
        }.resume()
         
    }
}
```

My view looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var fetcher = ArticlesFetcher()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(fetcher.articles.results) { article in
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(article.title)
                    Text(article.articleId)
                        .font(.system(size: 11))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What i don't understand is the view part - i am not able to point into the fields, with the example above i get compiler errors like *"Value of type '[Welcome]' has no member 'results'"* or *"Value of type 'Int' has no member 'title'"*

I think i may just not understand something aboutmy structure or how to loop through it.
Thanks for any advise.

Comment: `.articles` property is `[Welcome]` - i.e. an array of `Welcome` types. An array doesn't have a property `.results`. Each element of that array, which is a `Welcome` object, has the `.results` property. So you either need a double loop or revisit the design of your `ArticlesFetcher` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON starts with a `{` so it's a dictionary. And the type of `articles` is wrong.

Replace

```
@Published var articles = [Welcome]()
```

with

```
@Published var articles = [Result]()
```

and replace

```
let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode([Welcome].self, from: d)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.articles = decodedLists
}
```

with

```
let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: d)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.articles = decodedLists.results
}
```

---

Finally but not related replace meaningless

```
print ("Error")
```

with

```
print(error)
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot! I had also to adapt some changes to my view:
struct ContentView: View {

 @ObservedObject var fetcher = ArticlesFetcher()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
   List(fetcher.articles) { article in
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(article.title)
                    Text(article.articleID)
                        .font(.system(size: 11))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
} and it works now, thank you!